# fetching multiple columns of mysql table and echoing each row

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php/html code that echos a column from a mysql table called "tickets". 
These are the 3 columns in the table (member_id, ticket_id, ticket_result).

I want to be able to grab the info from the other columns in a specific row and echo that with the foreach loop. I just don't know how I would be able to do that because you can only have 1 array in a foreach loop so if I was to make add this line to the PHP Code I don't see how I could echo it in the foreach loop.

```
 $me3 = array(); 
$me2[] = $row->ticket_result;
```

PHP Code:

```
 public function tickets() { 
    $this->db_connection = new mysqli('', '', '', ''); 

    $sql = "SELECT ticket_result 
            FROM tickets 
            WHERE member_id = '1'"; 
    $query = $this->db_connection->query($sql); 

    $me2 = array(); 
    while ($row = $query->fetch_object()) { 
        $me2[] = $row->ticket_result;     
    } 
    return $me2; 
  } 
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<?php $me2 = $classLogin->tickets(); ?> 
       <?php foreach($me2 as $value) { ?> 
     <table> 
<thead> 
<th>Result</th> 
<th>ID</th>
</thead> 

<tr> 

<td><?php echo $value; ?> </td> 
<td>  </td>
<?php } ?> 
</tr> 

</table>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what your question ?

Comment: Select the other 2 columns in your query, then `$me2[] = $row->ticket_id;` etc. should do the trick. *You may need to use*  `fetch_assoc()` though. Try that.

Comment: In your query -> ` $sql = "SELECT member_id, ticket_id, ticket_result...` and in your php ->  `$me2[] = array('member_id'=>$row->member_id, 'ticket_id'=>$row->ticket_id, 'ticket_result'=>$row->ticket_result);`?

Comment: That was a rookie mistake forgetting to add the other 2 columns into the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only selecting one column of your table:

```
$sql = "SELECT ticket_result FROM tickets WHERE member_id = '1'";
```

Your statement should look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT member_id, ticket_id, ticket_result FROM tickets WHERE member_id = '1'";
```

Or:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE member_id = '1'";
```

Then you can retrieve your data with this:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_object()) { 
    $me2[$row->ticket_id]['ticket_result'] = $row->ticket_result;
    $me2[$row->ticket_id]['member_id'] = $row->member_id;
}
```

So you'll have an array (`$me2`) that contains keys according to your `ticked_id`s and each key is an array with the keys `ticket_result` and `member_id` which contain that data from your db.

Then you can implement your `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($me2 as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo $value['ticket_result'];
    echo $value['member_id'];
}
```

Also, if the HTML you have to print is not that much, I suggest you better use `echo` and *concatenate* a string withing a single `php` clause rather than *opening and closing* multiple `php` tags for every little php code you have to execute, your code would look like this:

```
<?php
    $me2 = $classLogin->tickets();
    echo
        '<table>
            <thead>
                <th>Result</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </thead>';
    foreach($me2 as $key => $value) {
        echo
            '<tr>
                <td>'.$value['ticket_result'].'</td>
                <td>'.$value['member_id'].'</td>
            </tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: I used your code above last night and it was working fine. I was playing with it as well and for some reason today it is only displaying one table with one row from my db instead of the 4 tables it was displaying yesterday. Could you take a look at this code and see if I could have made a mistake?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM tickets
            WHERE member_id = '1'";
             $query = $this->db_connection->query($sql); 
                $me2 = array();
               while ($row = $query->fetch_object()) { 
    $me2[$row->ticket_id]['ticket_result'] = $row->ticket_result;
    $me2[$row->ticket_id]['member_id'] = $row->member_id;
} 
                 return $me2;
     }

Comment: <?php foreach ($me2 as $key => $value) { ?>
<table class="table table-bordered ">
<thead>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Member ID</th>
<th>Result</th>
</thead>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $key  ?></td>
<td><?php echo $value['member_id'];  ?></td>
<td><?php echo $value['ticket_result'];?> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>

Comment: Did you make any change on the database? or did it just stopped working out of the nothing? if you use the code above again does it works again? chances are that something changed on your database.

Comment: I just added a couple of new rows into the db so I could see if it would display each new row and it did. And today it works but it is only displaying one row from the database.

Comment: Make sure your select criteria (i.e. the WHERE clause) is selecting more than one result, what is the output of `var_dump($me2);`?.

Comment: What did you mean by "Make sure your select criteria is selecting more than one result?". This was outputted when I did a var_dump. array(1) { [1]=> array(2) { ["ticket_result"]=> string(5) "LOSER" ["member_id"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Comment: What do you put instead of the `'1'` in `WHERE member_id = '1'`?

Comment: I put {$_SESSION['user_id']}. I don't think that is the problem either because even when I put '1' inside the WHERE it does the same thing. I think the problem is somewhere in the while loop where it is not putting all of the rows with the ticket_id of '1' into the $me2 array.

Comment: Are the values of `member_id` repeated on your table?

Comment: Yes all of the member_id's are '1'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56058/discussion-between-user3718799-and-arielnmz).

Comment: I sent a message in the chat if you could check it out.

Comment: Check the conversation